# PHP Object Inheritance result blank webpage

Tags: php, object, inheritance, parent-child

I have a parent object "Person" and then a child object "Student" but when I try to test out the child out "test_Student.php", no internal error 500 but just blank screen, any idea why? As I thought I should have at least "George" on the screen.

The following is the code that i have problem with.
Person.php:

```
class Person
{
    protected $firstName;
    protected $surName; 
    public function __construct(string $f, string $l){
        $this->getFirstName($f);
        $this->getSurName($l);
    }
    public function getFirstName(): string{
        return $this->firstName;
    }
    public function setFirstName(string $value){
        $this->firstName = $value;
    }
    public function getSurName(): string{
        return $this->surName;
    }
    public function setSurName(string $value){
        $this->surName = $value;
    }
}
```

Student.php

```
class Student extends Person
{
    protected $studentID;
    public function __construct(int $i,string $f, string $l)
    {
        parent::__construct($f,$l);
        $this->studentID = $i;
    }
    public function getStudentInfo(): string
    {
        return "Student Info: ".$this->studentID;   
    }
}
```

test_Student.php:

```
<?php
require("Student.php");
try
{
    $stud = new Student(1,"George","Orwell");
    echo $stud->getFirstName();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
   echo "v5: ".$e->getMessage();
}
catch(Error $e)
{
    echo "v7: ".$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: Check your logs. If you don't have an autoloader, the problem is that `Person` is undefined because you never load Person.php.

Comment: Semantically I'd argue that your Person is not a Person, but a PersonName. And if so, it makes no sense to extend Student from it. Instead the Student should have a PersonName. This is no use case for inheritance, but for Composition or Aggregation, e.g. `new Student(42, new PersonName("John", "Doe"));` or `new Student(42, "John", "Doe")` and then in the constructor `$this->studentName = new PersonName($first, $last);`

Comment: @EdCottrell: U r correct as i typed wrongly on set/get but the try/catch for some reason does not work and missed that part. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor for class `Person` is calling getters, not setters. Change it to this:

```
public function __construct(string $f, string $l){
    $this->setFirstName($f);
    $this->setSurName($l);
}
```

Whether or not that's the only problem, I'm not sure (e.g. `Student` may not be able to instantiate due to failure to load `Person.php` beforehand). You should check your error logs to see what's in there, as that will give you information about what the problem is. You can find the error log location by looking for the text `error_log` in your `php.ini` file and/or `.htaccess` file. Additionally, you can check your code for any reference to `ini_set("error_log", "/path/to/error.log");`